# Laravel advanced search query fix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a search form with multiple input and select boxes I need help to get if conditions in my query in order to each part works separately and all at once.

**here is my blade codes:**

```
<form action="{{route('advancesearch')}}" method="post">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="sidebar-title">
        <span>Advanced Search</span>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down show_sidebar_content" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- ./sidebar-title -->

      <div id="tags-filter-content" class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="filter-tag-group">

          @foreach($options as $option)
          <div class="tag-group">
            <p class="title">
              <span class="filter-title show_filter_content">{{$option->title}} <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></span>
            </p>
            <div class="filter-content">
              <div class="checkbox">
              @foreach($option->suboptions as $suboption)
              <label for="suboptions">
                <input name="suboptions[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$suboption->id}}">
                {{ucfirst($suboption->title)}}
              </label>
              @endforeach
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
          <!-- ./tag-group -->

          <div class="tag-group">
            <p class="title">
              <span class="filter-title show_filter_content">Brand <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></span>
            </p>
            <div class="filter-content">
              <div class="checkbox">
              @foreach($brands as $brand)
              <label for="brands">
                <input name="brands[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$brand->id}}">
                {{$brand->title}}
              </label>
              @endforeach
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ./tag-group -->

          <div class="tag-group">
            <p class="title">
              <span class="filter-title show_filter_content">Price Range <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span></span>
            </p>
            <div class="row filter-content">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="min_price" hidden>Min</label>
                  <input type="text" name="min_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Rp Min">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="max_price" hidden>Max</label>
                  <input type="text" name="max_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Rp Max">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- tag-group -->

          <div class="text-center mt-20">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">TERPAKAN</button>
          </div>

        </div><!-- ./filter-tag-group -->
      </div><!-- ./sidebar-content -->
    </form>
```

**and this is my route:**

```
Route::post('/advanced-search', 'frontend\SearchController@filter')->name('advancesearch');
```

**finally my function code is:**

```
public function advancedsearch(Request $request) {
        $brands = Brand::all(); // uses for other part of the page. (not related to search function)
        $options = Option::all(); // uses for other part of the page. (not related to search function)
        $suboptions = DB::table('product_suboption'); // where my product_id and subopyion_id saves

        //search function
        $products = Product::where(function($query){
            //getting inputs
            $suboptions2 = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
            $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? Input::get('min_price') : null;
            $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? Input::get('max_price') : null;
            $brands2 = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : [];

            //returning results
            $query->where('price','>=',$min_price)
                    ->where('price','<=',$max_price);
            })->get();

        return view('front.advancesearch', compact('products', 'brands', 'options'));
    }
```

## My models relations:

`product` model:

```
public function options(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
  }
  public function suboptions(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Suboption::class, 'product_suboption', 'product_id', 'suboption_id');
  }
public function brand(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
  }
```

`Option` model:

```
public function suboptions(){
     return $this->hasMany(Suboption::class, 'option_id');
  }

  public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

`Suboption` model:

```
public function option(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Option::class, 'option_id');
  }

  public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

`Brand` model:

```
public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

## note

My `brands` search is coming from products table where I have column `brand_id` for each product.

**BUT**

My `suboptions` come from 3rd table named `product_suboption` (as you see in my models codes) where i save `product_id` and `suboption_id`.

Comment: Your checkbox input fields do not have the name attribute set, so you can't get the value off of them, because they aren't sent. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Reduxx updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

After weeks of playing with codes finally I came to the right results for myself (in my case it works this way for others maybe works with other suggested answers)

```
public function advancedsearch(Request $request) {
    $options = Option::all();
    $brands = Brand::all();
    $brandss = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : [];
    $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? (int)Input::get('suboptions') : [];
    $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? (int)Input::get('min_price') : null;
    $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? (int)Input::get('max_price') : null;

    //codes
    if(count($request['suboptions'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->join('product_suboption', function ($join) {
        $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_suboption.product_id')
                 ->where('product_suboption.suboption_id', '=', $suboption);
        })
      ->paginate(12);
    }

    elseif(count($request['brands'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereIn('products.brand_id', $brandss)
      ->paginate(12);
    }

    elseif(count($request['min_price']) && count($request['max_price'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereBetween('price', [$min_price, $max_price])
      ->paginate(12);
    }


    return view('front.advancesearch', compact('products', 'brands', 'options'));
    }
```

> **NOTE:** most of my pricing issues solved with `(int)` as you see in my codes `(int)Input::get('min_price')` and
>   `(int)Input::get('max_price')`.

Special thanks to **Ravindra Bhanderi** for his `count($request['']` suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This is just to give an idea. You can use a multiple `->where()` and eager loading `->with()` for your query.
Take a look with this query below:

```
$products = Product::where('price', '>=', $min_price) // you get the max and min price 
        ->where('id', '<=', $max_price)->select('id')
        ->with([
            "brand" => function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('id', $brand_ids); // [1, 2, 3,...]
            },
            "specifications" => function ($query) {
                $query->where('some_column', '=', 'possible-value'); // single condition
            },
            "specifications.subspecifications" => function ($query) {
                $query->where([
                    'some_column' => 'possible-value',
                    'another_column' => 'possible-value'
                ]); // you can also pass arrays of condition
            }
        ])->get(); // This will return the products with the price set by the user
                   // Since we're just using ->with(), this will also return those products
                   // that doesn't match the other criteria specifications) so we 
                   // still need to filter it.
```

Finally, you can filter the products which matches the  `specifications`, 
 - the `product` with an empty `specifications` means this product does not match the criteria, therefore we'll have to remove it from the collection.

```
$filtered =  $products->filter(function ($product, $key) {
    return count($product->brand) > 0 && count($product->specifications) > 0;
    // add your other boolean conditions here
});

dd($filtered->toArray()); // your filtered products to return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel `orWhere` and `orWhereHas` to get results separately and all at once, let's say you do not select `min_price` and `max_price` but you have selected `brand` then all products with this brnad should be return, your query will look like this

```
$products = Product::orWhere('price','>=',$min_price)
->orWhere('price','<=',$max_price)
->orWhereHas('brand',function($query){
    $query->whereIn('id', $brand_ids);
})
->orWhereHas('suboptions',function($query){
    $query->whereIn('id', $suboptions_ids);
})
->orWhereHas('subspecifications',function($query){
    $query->whereIn('id', $subspecifications_ids);
})->get();
```

`$products` will have products collection If any of the condition stated in above query matched.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: min_price`

Comment: Inside `filter` method of `SearchController` you have to get inputs from your submitted form i-e `$min_price = $request->min_price` and then pass them into query. In the `$request->min_price` min_price is your input name.

Comment: `orwhere` doesn't work, we must have at least `1 where` then say `orwhere`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it. Note the use of `when` for simplifying optional where conditions (no need to set variables either), and the closure for constraining both the `whereHas` and the `with` (if you want to eager load the relationships).

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->when($request->min_price, function ($query, $min_price) {
        return $query->where('price', '>=', $min_price);
    })
    ->when($request->max_price, function ($query, $max_price) {
        return $query->where('price', '<=', $max_price);
    })
    ->when($request->suboptions, function ($query, $suboptions) {
        $suboptionsConstraint = function ($q) use ($suboptions) {
            return $q->whereIn('id', $suboptions);
        };
        return $query->whereHas('suboptions', $suboptionsContraint)
            ->with(['suboptions' => $suboptionsContraint]);
    })
    ->when($request->brands, function ($query, $brands) {
        $brandsConstraint = function ($q) use ($brands) {
            return $q->whereIn('id', $brands);
        };
        return $query->whereHas('brands', $brandsConstraint)
            ->with(['brands' => $brandsConstraint]);
    });
```

Comment: `Illegal operator and value combination.` on `$products = Product::where('price', '>=', $request->min_price)`

Comment: @mafortis that's because the prices are optional too, right? See the updated answer

Comment: yes they are, and i get this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` on ` return $q->whereIn('id', $suboptions);` PS: I think you should read my question update (note).

Comment: @mafortis do you get that error always or for specific values of `suboptions`?

Comment: my page wont load.

Comment: @mafortis I mean, if it fails when `suboptions` is empty, or it has a single value, or..... You could try `return $q->whereIn('id', (array) $suboptions);`

Comment: @mafortis you don't need to run the query to see the form the first time, right?

Comment: no, that was my bad i was trying to reload results that was why i got that error (sorry about that). but still it needs to get results from my 3rd table right?

Comment: @mafortis casting to array should prevent the error `Invalid argument...`, have you tried that?

Comment: casting what? and please tell me which part of `brands` code i suppose to say check in `brand_id`? as i said brands search comes from products id itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest tu use each separeted and its help you to feature easaly manupulate code

as your typical condition your sub_option come from third table last relation ship is used.

```
 if(count($request['suboptions'])) {

         $product->whereHas('options',function($options) use ($request) {

                   $options->whereHas('suboptions',function($suboption)use($request) {

                         $suboption->whereIn('id',$request['suboptions']);
                  });
         }); 
 }
```

for min price max price i assume your price in procuct table

```
   if(! empty($request['min_price'])) {

          $product->where('price','>=',$request['min_price']);
    }

 if(! empty($request['max_price'])) {

          $product->where('price','<=',$request['max_price']);
    }
```

for brand as you say brand_id column in product table then

```
   if(count($request['brands'])) {

          $product->whereIn('brand_id',$request['brands']);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for respond dude, but please see my codes, there is no product title input in my form and for my options please read my latest update `note` part.

Comment: its a example , actually development you can do on the base of my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach.

On your controller, change it to this:

```
public function advancedsearch(Request $request) {

$suboptions2 = request->suboptions ? request->suboptions : null;
$min_price = request->min_price ? request->min_price : null;
$max_price = request->max_price ? request->max_price : null;
$brands2 = request->brands ? request->brands : null;

$query = Product::select('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3')
->join('brands as b', 'b.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
...(others joins);

// here we do the search query
if($suboptions2){
    $query->where('suboptions_field', '=', $suboptions);
}

if($min_price && $max_price){
    $query->where(function($q2) {
                $q2->where('price', '>=', $min_price)
                    ->where('price', '<=', $max_price)
            });

}

if($brands2){
    $query->where('products.brand_id', '=', $brands2);
}

// others queries

// finish it with this
$query->get();

return view('front.advancesearch', compact('products', 'brands', 'options'));
```

I find doing it this way is very useful because it can be really easy to implement additional queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use to search using laravel eloquent with multiple input:

```
$input = Input::all(); //group all the inputs into single array
$product = Product::with('options','suboptions','brand');

//looping through your input to filter your product result
foreach ($input as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value!='') {
       if ($key == "max_price")
            $product = $product->where('price','<=', $value);
       elseif ($key == "min_price")
            $product = $product->where('price','>=', $value);
       elseif ($key == "brands")
            $product = $product->whereIn('brand_id', $value); //assuming that your Input::get('brands') is in array format
       elseif ($key == "suboptions")
            $product = $product->whereIn('suboption_id', $value);
    }
}
$product = $product->get();
```

The method above will return all products if no input is submitted, and will filter the result based on the input if available, on top of this it's also a good practice to sanitize your inputs with validations before proceeding with the query

Comment: `Illegal operator and value combination.`

Comment: It'll be helpful if you provide more details of the error like which line causes it, my guess is there's null or blank value in the input submitted. I've edited my answer for that

Answer (score 0):

**it is very simple to make dynamic search by using treats we can use this for all models I made this dynamic as possible**

This is a trait that can be used by any models

**This function will remove code repetitions into your project**

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $keyword, $columns = [], $relativeTables = [])
{
    if (empty($columns)) {
        $columns = array_except(
            Schema::getColumnListing($this->table), $this->guarded
        );
    }   

    $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword, $columns) {
        foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
            $clause = $key == 0 ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
            $query->$clause($column, "LIKE", "%$keyword%");

            if (!empty($relativeTables)) {
                $this->filterByRelationship($query, $keyword, $relativeTables);
            }
        }
    });

    return $query;
}
```

**Filter into relationship also**

```
private function filterByRelationship($query, $keyword, $relativeTables)
{
    foreach ($relativeTables as $relationship => $relativeColumns) {
        $query->orWhereHas($relationship, function($relationQuery) use ($keyword, $relativeColumns) {
            foreach ($relativeColumns as $key => $column) {
                $clause = $key == 0 ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
                $relationQuery->$clause($column, "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
            }
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to ask any question i will explane you