# Getting list of discounted products in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get all of my discounted products in one page, but it doesn't return results

> **while the exact same query return results in homepage.**

`function`

```
public function promotions() {
    $promotions = Discount::with('products')->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(12);
    return view('front.promotions', compact('promotions'));
  }
```

`route`

```
Route::get('/promotions', 'frontend\FrontendController@promotions')->name('promotions');
```

`blade`

```
@foreach($promotions as $product)
{{$product->title}} // return nothing!
@endforeach
```

here is dd of my `$product`

[image: promotions dd]

`dd code`

```
Discount {#686 ▼
  #table: "discounts"
  #dates: array:2 [▶]
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "value_from" => "2018-02-18"
    "value_to" => "2018-02-19"
    "amount" => "10000"
    "product_id" => 16
    "stock" => 25
    "created_at" => "2018-02-19 09:05:48"
    "updated_at" => "2018-02-19 09:47:10"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "products" => Product {#697 ▼
      #fillable: array:16 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:23 [▶]
      #original: array:23 [▼
        "id" => 16
        "title" => "new product"
        "slug" => "new-product"
        "imageOne" => "productone-1519001703.png"
        "imageTwo" => "producttwo-1519001703.jpg"
        "short_description" => """
          <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n
          <html>\r\n
          <head>\r\n
          </head>\r\n
          <body>\r\n
          <p>eagtheyh</p>\r\n
          </body>\r\n
          </html>
          """
        "description" => """
          <!DOCTYPE html>\r\n
          <html>\r\n
          <head>\r\n
          </head>\r\n
          <body>\r\n
          <p>shw4 bw 6r uwrurjw ryt jyhkiuggk</p>\r\n
          </body>\r\n
          </html>
          """
        "price" => "100000"
        "meta_description" => "gjyrj"
        "meta_tags" => "yrujr,ujrtsdjr,jrjurysj,"
        "arrivalDays" => "1"
        "height" => "546"
        "weight" => "56"
        "lenght" => "56"
        "width" => "56"
        "sku" => "47ghg"
        "stock" => "24"
        "status_id" => 1
        "brand_id" => 1
        "category_id" => 1
        "subcategory_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2018-02-19 07:55:03"
        "updated_at" => "2018-02-21 09:58:04"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #slugOptions: null
      #configSettings: array:4 [▶]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over discounts and products:

```
@foreach($promotions as $discount)
    {{ $discount->products->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object ` on `{{ $product->title }}`

Comment: @mafortis please put `{{ dd($product) }}` instead of this line and show results.

Comment: return `true` only\

Comment: @mafortis please show unfolded results of `dd($promotions)` in controller.

Comment: @mafortis looks like a discount has only one product. I've updated the code.

Comment: currently have one, I can assign unlimited products for discount, PS: i get this error on edited code `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: @mafortis change `product` to `products`

Comment: would you mind look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918176/laravel-advanced-search-query-fix

Comment: @mafortis I'm sorry, but the other question is not clear.

Comment: If you don't mind comment there i'll explain it fully, (I want make query to get my sidebar fields work as search form regardless users use all fields in there or only some of them)