# join two query together in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function:

```
    public function landings($slug){
        $landing = Landing::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    //use to get categories id stored in DB
        $cat = DB::table('landing_categories')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)->get();
        foreach ($cat as $key) {
          $id[] = $key->category_id;
        }

// use to get specifications id and compare it with products that have same specifications id's
        $subs = DB::table('landing_specifications')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)
        ->join('product_subspecification', function ($keys) {
            $keys->on('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', 'landing_specifications.subspecification_id');
        })
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
        ->get();
    // dd($subs);

// using this to get result of 2 queries above at once
        $prod = DB::table('products')
        ->whereIn('products.category_id', $id)
        ->groupby($subs)
        ->get();
        return view('front.landing', compact('landing', 'prod'));
      }
```

queries: `$cat` & `$subs` are working as expected and returning the results that i'm looking for.

> **my issue is how to bind those two in `$prod` query?**

so far I can use `cat` by `whereIn` but as you see `$subs` and `$prod` both try to getting `DB::table('products')` and that's the problem I guess.

This error I get:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional
>   parameters (SQL: select * from `products` where
>   `products`.`category_id` in (3, 4) group by
>   `[{"id":1,"landing_id":8,"s // to be continued...

PS:
If I use `->union($subs)` instead of `->groupby($subs)` I will get:

> Method getBindings does not exist.

## UPDATE

`dd($id);`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 3
  1 => 4
]
```

`dd($subs);`

```
Collection {#721 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#710 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"landing_id": 8
      +"subspecification_id": 1
      +"product_id": 1
      +"title": "product one"
      +"slug": "product-one"
      +"imageOne": "product-1517990897.jpg"
      +"imageTwo": "product-1517990897.png"
      +"short_description": "<p>this is first testing product</p>"
      +"description": "<p>this is first testing product this is first testing product this is first testing product this is first testing product this is first testing product this is ▶"
      +"price": "10000000"
      +"meta_description": null
      +"meta_tags": null
      +"arrivalDays": "2"
      +"height": "100"
      +"weight": "1"
      +"lenght": "100"
      +"width": "100"
      +"sku": "1985629"
      +"stock": "16"
      +"status_id": 1
      +"brand_id": 2
      +"category_id": 1
      +"subcategory_id": 2
      +"created_at": "2018-02-07 15:05:00"
      +"updated_at": "2018-02-28 14:16:46"
    }
    1 => {#716 ▶}
    2 => {#714 ▶}
    3 => {#720 ▶}
    4 => {#718 ▶}
  ]
}
```

PS: when I get `$cat` and `$subs` together it should reduce result to `1` which is my correct answer base on y data saved.

Comment: I think, You need similar outcomes from these two query to combine together so that you can make union query

Comment: @SagarGautam sorry didn't catch it, meaning?

Comment: Can you add sample output of the `$cat` and `$prod` ?

Comment: @SagarGautam sure.

Comment: Where are $cat and $prod above ?

Comment: @SagarGautam `dd($id);` is from `$cat` foreach. $prod still not working i dd what?

Comment: You can't do groupBy in query like that

Comment: @SagarGautam updated,

Comment: Its quite confusing :D

Comment: @SagarGautam :)) we are here to do hard jobs aren't we? :-D maybe you can help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918176/laravel-advanced-search-query-fix

Comment: There are six answer already, you've not get answer yet ?

Comment: @SagarGautam I just published solved answer :)

Comment: COngrats you've got solution finally :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

I mixed my `$subs` and `$prod` like below and its working perfectly:

```
$prod = DB::table('landing_specifications')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)
    ->join('product_subspecification', function ($keys) {
        $keys->on('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', 'landing_specifications.subspecification_id');
    })
    ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
    ->whereIn('products.category_id', $id)
    ->groupby('products.id')
    ->get();
```